# re.findall() sometimes returning all sometimes returning last

Tags: python, regex

This returns only the last occurrence in data

```
re.findall('data-hovercard-id="[\w\W]*"><span>([\w\W]*)</span></a',data)
```

Whereas this returns all occurrences in the data

```
re.findall('class="business-attribute[\s]price-range">([\W]*)</',data)
```

I can't share the data for privacy reasons, but this is scraping and old static html of yelp.
Not sure if the structure is still the same.

Any ideas? I'm trying to get all occurrences for both

Comment: `"[\w\W]*"` needs to be non-greedy i.e. `"[\w\W]*?"` or better yet use `"[^"]*"`

Comment: Given that these are two different regexes and you can't show us the actual content it is matching against, at best we can speculate. E.g. one general guess is maybe your html elements are on multiple lines and your first regex doesn't account for that. On that note.. you should be using a DOM Parser not regex for this sort of thing.

Comment: Nick seems to be right, but just in case the linked question doesn't help, please ask a new question and include a [mre]. BTW isn't `[\w\W]` the same as `.`?